# Database design to track student attendance

Tags: mysql, database-design, php

I was having a doubt regarding the design of a database table to track students' attendance. Currently, my table `students` have atleast `4000` students.

Creating a database for attendance to track their attendance will have almost `4000*30days*12months => ~ 1,400,000` rows (neglecting vacations/ sundays).

The attendance table will have:

```
id (INT)
student_id (INT) 
course_id (INT)
data (DATETIME)
present/absent (TINYINT, as I'll store 1/0)
comments
```

I'm using `PHP/MySql`. With a table becoming so large, is there any other way?

Comment: 1.4 Million rows per year are not that many. But I find it hard to understand, if this is an attendance table, where is the date or the classroom or subject these students are attending at? And what is the `id` supposed to store?

Comment: You may be able to get away without storing an entry in your attendance table if the student is actually present.  Also, what about half-days, or deciphering between excused/unexcused absences?

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, i'll store all those things as well. My  biggest concern was that of the large number of rows. So, I framed the question in a hurry.

Comment: @AaronW.: I'll be storing those as well. My biggest concern was that of the large number of rows. So, I framed the question in a hurry.

Comment: I can only assume that ID is a foreign key into the table containing the properties of the lecture. Am I correct?

Answer (score 9):

To expand more on @Twinkles alternative, I'm concerned about why you're storing present and absent students in your attendance data. Is it because you want to be able to run a report that shows all kids and whether they were absent on a given day? There's a better way to do it.

Most systems I've seen store either the that the student is present (*Positive attendance*) or the student is absent (*Negative attendance*, although rarely referred to by that name). The decision on which to use came down to the structure and reporting requirements of the school *(and whoever they report to)*.

If you're school is concerned when the student is absent for reasons like having to track Truant students, you should use a standard (negative) attendance structure. Most K-12 schools in the US  do it this way.

If you're school only awards credit for courses after a verified number of hours have been completed (e.g. *Johnny doesn't pass the course until he's completed his coursework and attended 12 sessions of the class*), then a positive attendance structure could be used.

Assuming your data looked like this: (Ignoring the course_id in your example for simplicity)

```
Attendance: 
id | student_id | date       | 
------------------------------
1  | 2          | 2013-10-24 | 

Students:
student_id | student_name   | 
-----------------------------
1          | Johnny Johnson |
2          | Bobby Tables   |
3          | Suzie Smith    |
```

To get a report of all the kids at your school and their attendance status for the day, you could run a query like:

```
SELECT s.student_id, s.student_name
,  CASE WHEN a.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Absent' ELSE 'Present' END as attendance_status
FROM Students s
LEFT JOIN Attendance a on s.student_id=a.student_id AND a.date = '2013-10-24'
```

Which would return:

```
Result :
student_id | student_name   | attendance_status |
-------------------------------------------------
1          | Johnny Johnson | Present           |
2          | Bobby Tables   | Absent            |
3          | Suzie Smith    | Present           |
```

Comment: Hi, In return I will only get the students list if and only if one student is absent, 
How will I get the students list if all the students are present?

Answer (score 3):

You will very probably define an index over *ID*, *student_ID* and *presence*. Since these three values are represented by 9 byte, the whole index will be less than 20MB in size and will fit completely in your memory. I wouldn't worry about it.

Alternative: you could consider only storing a row for every student that missed the lecture.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a good case for archiving or decreasing granularity. I suspect the exact data becomes less relevant over time. My personal preference would be to have three levels of granularity: daily, weekly and yearly. After data is over a week old you summarise it to weekly. After it's over a year old, summarise it to yearly. I would've said monthly too, but the week to month mapping isn't precise.