# Student Attendance, null not returning

Tags: mysql, case

My question is based on the answer given [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52006/database-design-to-track-student-attendance)

```
 Attendance: 
id | student_id | date       | 
------------------------------
1  | 2          | 2013-10-24 | 

Students:
student_id | student_name   | 
-----------------------------
1          | Johnny Johnson |
2          | Bobby Tables   |
3          | Suzie Smith    |
To get a report of all the kids at your school and their attendance status for the day, you could run a query like:

SELECT s.student_id, s.student_name
,  CASE WHEN a.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Absent' ELSE 'Present' END as attendance_status
FROM Students s
LEFT JOIN Attendance a on s.student_id=a.student_id
WHERE a.date = '2013-10-24'
Which would return:

Result :
student_id | student_name   | attendance_status |
-------------------------------------------------
1          | Johnny Johnson | Present           |
2          | Bobby Tables   | Absent            |
3          | Suzie Smith    | Present           |
```

I have a similar query but it is not returning null values in this case present but its only retunring absent

```
Result that I am getting :
student_id | student_name   | attendance_status |
-------------------------------------------------      |
2          | Bobby Tables   | Absent            |     |
```

My query looks like

```
SELECT
student.StudentID,
student.Name,
CASE WHEN attendance.StudentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Present' ELSE 'Absent' END as Attendance_Status
FROM
student
Left JOIN attendance ON student.StudentID = attendance.StudentID
where
attendance.Date = '2015-03-30'
```

Comment: Note that the answer given in the original question has now been fixed based on the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get desired results `attendance.Date = '2015-03-30'` should be part of `LEFT JOIN`, not `WHERE`:

```
SELECT .... 
FROM
student
Left JOIN attendance ON student.StudentID = attendance.StudentID
AND attendance.Date = '2015-03-30'
```

Comment: Just one more thing if I am not asking too much, maybe you could help me with. If I want to display results for multiple dates but same table how could I do that?

Comment: @ Ali Shaikh: something like `AND attendance.Date IN ( '2015-03-30','2015-03-31') ` should do the job.

Comment: that did not work. let me rephrase my question. I want to get the result for different dates in different columns. Each result in its respective date column

Comment: @Ali Shaikh : search for pivoting.